# PHP expression for class constant

Tags: php, string, constants

I'm trying to figure out why I get and exception with this code.

```
class Test {
    const test = "Two " .
                 "rows.";
}
```

I get an exception on the row containing the const:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in
>   /home/BZUMUL/prog.php on line X

I was going to switch to heredoc but then I got too curious so I couldn't stop trying to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Class Constants](http://php.net/language.oop5.constants):

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, a result of a mathematical operation, or a function call.

So you cannot use an expression for the constant value.